# Need to apply sequential CSS property to all nth-child without javascript/jquery

Tags: css

I am looking for a solution to apply sequential CSS property like `top:10px,20px,30px`.... to each nth-child without using jquery or javascript. For example:

First `li` within `ul` should get `top:10px`, second `li` should get `20px` and so on.

Comment: You could take a look at SASS / SCSS where you can create loops which are compiled to regular css: http://www.alwaystwisted.com/articles/2014-03-06-even-better-each-loops-with-sass-33

Comment: actually prepocessors can be an option but is it possible to handle it through normal CSS that is my quest.

Comment: No it isn't possible with **pure - standard** CSS.